# How can I edit navigation bar to take out a link when admin user signs in?

Tags: php, html

The nav prior to sign in or register has the following links:
Home,
Blog,
Write a Blog,
Sign in,
Register,

When a normal user signs in the nav links will change to:
Hello (name of user),
Home,
Blog,
Write a blog,
Logout,

When the admin logs in the nav displays the following:
Hello (name of user),
Home,
Blog,
Write a blog,
Admin,
Logout,

My issue is I would like to remove the link 'write a blog' when the admin signs in.  Any advice on how I can adapt my code to do this would be great.  Below is the HTML & Php code in the header.php:

```
<header>
    <div class="wrap-header zerogrid">
        <div id="logo"><a href="/"><img src="/assets/images/logo_blog.png"/></a></div>
        <nav>
            <div class="wrap-nav">
                <div class="menu">
                    <ul class="list-unstyled">
                        <? if ($_SESSION['user']['first_name']): ?>
                            <li><a href="#"><i class="icon fa fa-user"></i> Hello <?= $_SESSION['user']['first_name'] ?></a></li>
                        <? endif ?>
                        <li><a href="/"><i class="icon fa fa-home"></i> Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/blog"><i class="icon fa fa-book"></i> Blog</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/payment"><i class="icon fa fa-pencil"></i> Write a Blog</a></li>
                         <? if ($_SESSION['user']['level'] >= 2): ?>
                            <li><a href="/admin"><i class="icon fa fa-pencil"></i> Admin</a></li>
                        <? endif ?>
                        <? if ($_SESSION['user']['first_name']): ?>
                            <li><a href="?action=logout"><i class="icon fa fa-sign-in"></i> Logout</a></li>
                        <? else: ?>
                            <li><a href="/sign_in"><i class="icon fa fa-sign-in"></i> Login</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/register"><i class="icon fa fa-pencil"></i> Register</a></li>
                            <? endif ?>
                    </ul>               
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>
</header>
```

It is probably something easy, I do tend to over complicate things! Thank you in advance.

Comment: You're going to do it just line the line below for the menu item ADMIN. But you have to determine what condition to test for the ADMIN user in your IF statement.

Comment: You've already (implicity) done that for the logout and signin / register. What is the problem? `<? if ($_SESSION['user']['level'] < 2): ?> <li><a href="/payment"><i class="icon fa fa-pencil"></i> Write a Blog</a></li> <? endif ?>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your replies.  It really was something simple solved with an if statement:

```
<nav>
        <div class="wrap-nav">
            <div class="menu">
                <ul class="list-unstyled">
                    <? if ($_SESSION['user']['first_name']): ?>
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="icon fa fa-user"></i> Hello <?= $_SESSION['user']['first_name'] ?></a></li>
                    <? endif ?>
                    <li><a href="/"><i class="icon fa fa-home"></i> Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/blog"><i class="icon fa fa-book"></i> Blog</a></li>
                    <? if ($_SESSION['user']['level'] < 2): ?>
                        <li><a href="/payment"><i class="icon fa fa-pencil"></i> Write a Blog</a></li>
                    <? else: ?>
                        <li><a href="/admin"><i class="icon fa fa-pencil"></i> Admin</a></li>
                    <? endif ?>
                    <? if ($_SESSION['user']['first_name']): ?>
                        <li><a href="?action=logout"><i class="icon fa fa-sign-in"></i> Logout</a></li>
                    <? else: ?>
                        <li><a href="/sign_in"><i class="icon fa fa-sign-in"></i> Login</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/register"><i class="icon fa fa-pencil"></i> Register</a></li>
                        <? endif ?> 
                </ul>               
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one approach where variables are set and validated before processing markup content. May provide a clear, clean code.

```
<?php

// 1. get session user object
$user   = (isset($_SESSION['user'])) ? $_SESSION['user'] : null;

// 2. set vars
if($user) {
   if(isset($user['first_name'])) {
     $first_name = $user['first_name'];
   }
   if(isset($user['level'])) {
     $level = $user['level'];
   }
}

// 3. set flag (optional) or access $level directly
if(isset($level)) {
  $isAdmin = ($level === "Admin") ? true: false;
}

// normal user: Hello (name of user), Home, Blog, Write a blog, Logout,
// admin logs : Hello (name of user), Home, Blog, Write a blog, Admin, Logout,

?>
```

and the markups...

```
<header>
    <div class="wrap-header zerogrid">
        <div id="logo"><a href="/"><img src="/assets/images/logo_blog.png"/></a></div>
        <nav>
            <div class="wrap-nav">
                <div class="menu">
                    <ul class="list-unstyled">

                       <!-- code omited -->              
                        <?php
                           if(isset($isAdmin) and $isAdmin) {
                              // display markup for Admin <li>
                           }
                         ?>    

                    </ul>               
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>
</header>
```

Hope this helps.